# How to display parent category with first level childs (Drupal)?

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy

How to display categories with views like this?

**Category1**

Subcategory1, Subcategory2, Subcategory3...

**Category2**

Subcategory1, Subcategory2, Subcategory3...

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with help of views too, I have implemented this at my workplace if you need I will provide you the export of my view.

I am showing here, the complete scenario what I understood, with the main points what you required, to achieve the exact view:
 - I have one Vocabulary named "Test"
 - Test has two Parent categories, category 1 and category 2.
 - Each category has subcategories: For example

**Category 1**

- sub category 1
- sub category 2

**Category 2**

- sub category 3
- sub category 4

Output you want to Display:

Category1

Subcategory1, Subcategory2, Subcategory3...

Category2

Subcategory1, Subcategory2, Subcategory3...

***Steps to achieve desired view:***

1. Create a view of Taxonomy Terms for vocabulary "Test"
2. Add Field "Term Name"
3. Create Relationship for Taxonomy Parent Term
4. Add Relation in added field "Term Name".
5. Add a global PHP field, where you will get parent term tid in $data variable.
6. Use a simple SELECT query to fetch subcategories using JOIN, tables you need are taxonomy_term_data and taxonomy_term_hierarchy.
7. show all the subcategories separated by ',' or any other desired separator.
8. Lastly you need to group by with added field name "Term Name".

After doing all these steps, you will definitely get the desired view result.

Hope this will help you, if you found any issue, free feel to reply. 
I can also provide you the export of my view, if you required.